# Using hcSticky to make content scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use the JQuery plugin, hcSticky to make my fixed content scroll. But for some reason I cannot get it to work right. What could I be doing wrong?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/T6gc2/

Here's the documentation: http://someweblog.com/hcsticky-jquery-floating-sticky-plugin/

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#newsfeed-left').hcSticky();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you misunderstood how hcSticky works.

This is how it should look like:

http://jsfiddle.net/gBCk9/

In order for hcSticky to work, you should have some content on the page, that is bigger than your element you want to float.
And second thing, you shouldn't set `position:fixed` by yourself to it, the plugin does it for you.

Comment: I didn't know that, about content bigger than floating element. Now I realize it is logical :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a scrollbar? if so you could just add an overflow-y like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/jquery4u/FKaWr/

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```